# How are point-dependent concepts such as correlation functions, renormalization, cluster decomposition...etc interpreted in axiomatic QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, correlation-functions, wightman-fields

In traditional quantum field theory we often speak about things happening at a point. For example, the correlation function
$$\langle 0 | \phi(x) \phi(y)\ | 0\rangle \tag{1}$$
can be thought of the probability for a particle to be created at $y$ and then annihilated at $x$. Similarly, the idea behind the cluster decomposition is that particles that are space-like separated cannot influence each other, and so the corresponding $S$ matrix factorizes. Renormalization is also often thought of as things happening point-wise.

I am struggling transferring this intuition to the setting of axiomatic QFT, using either the Wightman or the Osterwalder-Schrader axioms. Here everything is spoken in terms of distributions so it no longer makes sense to speak of things happening at a point. In this case, what is the interpretation of a Wightman function
$$\mathcal{W}(f_1, f_2) = \langle 0 | \phi(f_1)\phi(f_2) | 0\rangle? \tag{2}$$

Is the idea that, for example, $f_1$ has support containing $x$ and $f_2$ has support containing $y$ and so (2) is a "smeared" version of (1)? In this view, is the cluster decomposition simply a statement about when the supports of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are space-like separated? How is renormalization viewed in this setting?